# send parameter to a function though dynamically generated li onclick

Tags: jquery, ajax

now i know the concept od **DOM** and **Data Binding** i am well aware of my issue the problem is how to address it!

i have set of li's inside a ul dynamically generated by server response on ajax now what i need to do is on every li i need to add a function which accepts two parameters here's my ajax code

```
success: function(data){


            //console.log(data);
            //var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(JSONObject);
            var list = $("#suggesstion-box").append('<ul id="country-list"></ul>').find('ul');

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                 list.append("<li class='clickfunction' onclick=clickfunction("+data[i].lead_id+","+data[i].value+")>"+data[i].value+"</li>");

            }

            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(list);
            $(".search-box").css("background","#FFF");

        }
```

now what i want to do is i want to pass the values of **data[i].lead_id** and **data[i].value** into a function now the issue is the li are generated dynamically so they are not binned to the function as i result it gives me **function not defined error** now i can solve this by using the jquery **live** method

```
$('.clickfunction').live('click', function(){
         alert("here");
        });
```

now this works fine the issue is  the parameters! because when we call normal functions of javascript we can pass parameters into them but what about in this case can we somehow pass parameters to live function? or is there another better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use attributes:

```
success: function(data){


            //console.log(data);
            //var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(JSONObject);
            var list = $("#suggesstion-box").append('<ul id="country-list"></ul>').find('ul');

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                 list.append("<li class='clickfunction' lead-id='" + data[i].lead_id + "' lead-value='" + data[i].value + "'>"+data[i].value+"</li>");

            }

            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(list);
            $(".search-box").css("background","#FFF");

        }


$('.clickfunction').live('click', function(){
         var lead_id = $(this).attr("lead-id");
         var lead_value = $(this).attr("lead-value");
         console.log(lead_id + " - " + lead_value);
        });
```

Comment: that is perfect! i went over this concept of attributes but couldn't implement it properly,just one question we can define as much attributes as we want ? like in this case we created lead-id etc?

Comment: Yes, you can create as much attributes as you like.

Comment: why the downvote my question looks good and unique! suspended my account :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var li = $('<li>'); // create new <li> element
    li.text(data[i].value); // set text, class, whatever you want
    li.on('click', function () { // bind to click event on in
        console.log(data[i]); // do what you want with the data
    });
    list.append(li); // append to the list
}
```

This way you do not need the `live` call at all. Btw `live` has been deprecated long time ago (v1.7). You should use `on` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/live/